# Group and Stack data in Kendo UI Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a json data like:

```
arr = [{ Name: 'PAVI', value: 3}, {Name: 'Crystal', value: 2}, {Name: 'PAVI', value: 6}, {Name: 'Crystal', value: 11}]
```

How to stack data with similar Name in Kendo UI Chart? Here is my code for this moment

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
        data: data,
        group: {
            field: 'Name'
        }
    },
series: [{
        name: "Total Sales",
        field: "value",
        stack: true
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        field: 'Name'
    },
```

Actually here is the structure of real data that i use

```
{
 Account:"Piscopo Cash and Carry"
 AccountName:"Piscopo Cash and Carry"
 Category:""
 MainCategory:"Other"
 TotalQty:146
 TotalSales:9747.616
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found the solution by setting group to MainCategory (dont even think that solution is so simple XD )

Comment: With that structure, how you would expect it to be stacked? Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: I need to group data by name, so each row have only one bar chart with stacked data value

Comment: With the new data structure you have added it is actually possible. But the sample data structure you provided cannot be stacked. That was the problem. I thought that was your final data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant by "stack" because with that data structure, I don't see any way how you could stack it. However, if you wanted to sum the values with the same name and show the total, then you can use the aggregate option in the chart.

Here's how to do that: This will sum PAVI's & Crystal's values and show only two columns in the chart.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data,
    group: {
        field: "Name", aggregates: [{
            field: "value", aggregate: "sum"
        }]
    }
});
```

Notice the `group` and `aggregate` options.

Here's the full code:

```
var data = [
    { Name: 'PAVI', value: 3 },
    { Name: 'Crystal', value: 2 },
    { Name: 'PAVI', value: 3 },
    { Name: 'Crystal', value: 10 }
];

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data,
    group: {
        field: "Name", aggregates: [{
            field: "value", aggregate: "sum"
        }]
    }
});

dataSource.read();

$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: getChartData(dataSource),
    series: [{
        type: "column",
        field: "value",
        categoryField: "Name"
    }]
});


function getChartData(dataSource) {    
    var chartData = [];
    var view = dataSource.view();
    for (var idx = 0; idx < view.length; idx++) {
        chartData.push({
            Name: view[idx].value,
            value: view[idx].aggregates.value.sum
        });
    }
    return chartData;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/y1gacd0m/6/)

Hope it helps :) Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: That's a little bit not that solution, because I need to group data by name and have one column for each one, and show not the sum but the **stacked** bars that I have for this data